# Bool concatenation in tuples and vectors?

Tags: c++, binary, boolean

For writing/reading files, I do some low-level/binary manipulation with tuples and vectors.
When I do `std::vector<bool> v(8)` or `std::tuple<bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool...>`, do I have the guarantee that the boolean are not concatenated ? (and consequently the vector and the tuples weights at least n bytes (where n is the number of booleans).

Comment: What do you mean with “concatenated”? Bit-packed? Anyway, you have no such guarantees for `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: Yes I mean bit-packed. If they are bit-packed, what would be the result of &v[0] and &v[1] ? They point to the same address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implementation-defined whether [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/cpp/container/vector_bool) is bit-packed. Its interface doesn't provide any way to directly access the bool values, thus trying to access the underlying array directly, you will certainly get burnt at some point.

[`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/cpp/utility/tuple) is a generalization of `std::pair`. Thus `std::tuple<bool, bool, bool>` is equivalent to `struct SomeStruct { bool a, b, c; };`, in other words, bool values won't be bit-packed.

Answer (score -1):

"Vector specialization: vector< bool >
The vector class template has a special template specialization for the bool type.

This specialization is provided to optimize for space allocation: In this template specialization, each element occupies only one bit.." quoted from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).